# Protect Excel Worksheet using VBScript Allowing Sorting and Filtering

Tags: excel, vbscript

I would like to use vbscript to protect a worksheet (without a password), but allow sorting and filtering. The [protect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel) has parameters for controlling this in VBA: **AllowSorting** and **AllowFiltering**, but I can't figure out how to pass these parameters to the protect method in vbscript. Any variant of parameters I try is just interpreted as a password. Is it possible?

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("file.xls")
objWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Protect
```

Answer (score 0):

objWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Protect "", True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, False